# PHP / MySQLi drop-down empty

Tags: php, mysqli

Im just starting out with MySQL and PHP. Im trying to create a drop-down menu, to pick a certain competence within a company.

Later on, i want a total of 3 dropdowns, so that i can combine user/competence/avaliable date, to display sort of a calendar to show which users are avaliable a certain date, with information about their competence.

However, the code below just returns this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZKqc.png)

The same query to the database returns 12 values.

What am i doing wrong? I get no errors, just a blank drop-down.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Greetings. </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "service");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
echo "<br />";

$query_kompetens = "SELECT kompetens FROM kompetens";
$kompetens = mysqli_query($con, $query_kompetens);

echo "<select name='Kompetens'>";
echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($kompetens)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Kompetens'] . "'>" . $row['Kompetens'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
;
?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code, actually you used $row['Kompetens'] instead of $row['kompetens'].

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Greetings. </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "servicedesk");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
echo "<br />";

$query_kompetens = "SELECT kompetens FROM kompetens";
$kompetens = mysqli_query($con, $query_kompetens);

echo "<select name='Kompetens'>";
echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($kompetens)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['kompetens'] . "'>" . $row['kompetens'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
;
?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you used $row['Kompetens'] instead of  $row['kompetens'].